# >>> from app import db Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

While running the code in terminal in python, after importing the `db` which is written inside my code through `app`, it was saying that the module is not found. Can any one help me out

```
> from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Comment: Is "app" a  custom module ?

Comment: where is the 'app' folder/file located?